Dimensions And dimensional Formula
I was recently studying about dimensions and I am stuck at a question that why Angles and exponents are dimensionless?

Have you seen formulas like $\sin\theta=\theta-\frac{1}{3!}\theta^3+…$? If so, can you subtract a unit-cubed from a unit?

The same applies to $e^x=1+x+\frac12x^2+…$ and thus to any other exponential.

@Ghoster This is a non-convincing argument. It ignores the fact that the $n-$th term of a Taylor expansion is of the form $\frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n f}{dx^n} x^n$. Therefore, whatever dimension $x$ may have does not appear in the terms of the expansion. Indeed, changing the units of $x$ will change the values of the coefficients.

It’s the argument I was taught, and I find it convincing. No physicist does $e^{2 meters}$.

@Ghoster, me too; I have been taught that way. But I realized it was one of the many urban legends plaguing physics.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 That's not an urban legend, it's a valid opportunity to do units checking.   The casual 'we can ignore sigma-squared when we do a least squares fit' is a classic omission of an important part of the formula.   Units checking is always going to find that the exponent in a measure formula is unitless.

@Whit3rd, where did you read that I am saying that unit checking is not important? My point (not only mine; I could give references to the literature) is that the Taylor expansion is not a solid argument for justifying that the argument of non-monomial functions should be dimensionless. The reason is elsewhere.

@Whit3rd see this paper for an expanded argument: https://fermatslibrary.com/s/can-one-take-the-logarithm-or-the-sine-of-a-dimensioned-quantity-or-a-unit-dimensional-analysis-involving-transcendental-functions

This is an interesting question because the real answer is "it depends."  There are those who will say that angles are dimensionless, but that is not a universally agreed upon opinion.
The usual argument that angles are dimensionless because radians are a ratio of two lengths: the radius of a circle and the length along the circumference.  Thus their dimensionality is something along the lines of $\frac{\text{length}}{\text{length}}$, which is of course a dimensionless value.
However, the real key is that if you correctly account for units, you must arrive at the right answer.  It is possible to think of angles as their own sort of dimension.  Several software libraries (such as Boost.units) take this opinion.  So it's not crazy to think of them as having a dimension.
As for exponents, they often do have units.  If you think about it, its hard to have a dimension for $x$ in an expression like $2^x$.  However, like angles, there are many who argue that they do have a unit.  Concepts like decibels, Shannons, and the Neper are used for various bases (10, 2, and e, respectively).
However, life is often easier if we don't have to worry about such details.  Accordingly, we typically do try to make exponents dimensionless when it is reasonable to do so.

So according to this answer ratios are also dimensionless.

Ratios between values of the same dimension are indeed dimensionless.  A ratio of 3 meters to 1 meter is a 3:1 ratio (no units).  If you include more general divisions in ratios, such as 3 meters to 1 second, that "ratio" would have units (historically such divisions were not considered ratios).  Indeed, this is a very common trick for getting dimensionless values for your exponents or arguments to functions like sine and cosine.  You'll see stuff like $\frac t \tau$ all over the place, where $t$ is a variable in time, and $\tau$ is a constant in time.
